# Как можно найти элемент по его атрибуту?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Использую PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Как можно найти такой блок?

```
 <div style="display: inline-block;">FIND_ME</div>
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации написано, что поиск осуществляется по CSS-селектору. Цитирую:

> mixed find ( string $selector [, int $index] ) - Find children by the CSS selector

Очевидно, что нужно использовать соответствующий CSS-селектор:

```php
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Ищем нужные элементы
foreach($html->find('[style="display: inline-block;"]') as $element) {
  // Делаем дела
}
```

Comment: Вроде так будет точнее  `$html->find('div[style=display: inline-block;]',0);`

Comment: @Hardc0re, согласен, но мы не знаем, что нужно автору. Он ищет блок по атрибуту, а не по элементу, плюс не говорит о том, что ему нужен один такой блок.